# Spring EJB3 JNDI Environment Variables Problem

Tags: spring, ejb-3.0, weblogic

I am having problem in calling an remote EJB on another server. The JNDI environment variables seem to be used when spring lookup the EJB home on startup. However, those environment variables seem not being used when the EJB methods are invoked and therefore my program keep calling the local server for the EJB.

I am using Spring 2.5.6, Weblogic 10.3.0 and EJB3.0

My EJB spring config is as below:

```
<jee:remote-slsb id="myService"
    jndi-name="myService#com.test.MyService"
    business-interface="com.test.MyService">
  <jee:environment>
    java.naming.factory.initial=weblogic.jndi.WLInitialContextFactory
    java.naming.provider.url=t3://remoteserver:7001
    java.naming.security.principal=username
    java.naming.security.credentials=password
  </jee:environment>
</jee:remote-slsb>
```

Has anyone encountered this problem before?

I have tried to run my code on WebLogic 10.3.3 and it is working properly. I guess there may be some problem with Spring 2.5.6 and WebLogic 10.3.0.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was not related to Spring but WebLogic 10gR3 (10.3.0). My EJB remote methods have used Java Generics where WebLogic 10gR3.doesn't yet support

http://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=838453&tstart=0